# How to use regular expression in hbase

Tags: regex, hbase

I am new to HBase and trying to do some scan query. Below is my sample data:

```
2470883371  column=card info:CARD_TYPE, timestamp=1439291958723, value=MASTERCARD
2470883371  column=card info:UNIQUE_NO, timestamp=1439291958767, value=991-761-828-450
2470883371  column=card info:EXPIRY_DATE, timestamp=1439291958747, value=Wed Oct 03 18:09:34 IST 2018
3495415072  column=card info:CARD_TYPE, timestamp=1439291958835, value=MASTERCARD
3495415072  column=card info:UNIQUE_NO, timestamp=1439291959618, value=973-470-914-600
3495415072  column=card info:EXPIRY_DATE, timestamp=1439291958850, value=Wed Oct 03 18:09:34 IST 2018
```

I want to query like:

1. **Retrive all results that start from rowkey id 2470883 (actual value is 2470883371)**
2. **Retrive all results whose unique number starts from 991-761-828 (actual value is 991-761-828-450)**

Is it possible in HBase using scan? Basically I want to know how to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Filters and Comparators, for example RegexStringComparator https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RegexStringComparator.html

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression should match what you need:

```
((?:^2470883.*?$)|(?:^.*?value=991-761-828.*?$))
```

Comment: scan 'transaction', {FILTER =>('?:^2470883.*?$')} .is this the way i should do it??